# Implementation behind (Nullable Type).HasValue

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Generally when we access a property of a object which has a `null` value, we will face a `null` exception. But we when we access `HasValue` property of a `Nullable` `object`, it will gives a result. I would like to know what would be implementation behind the sceen.

Comment: The .NET source is [available online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't know already, nullable types, like `int?` are just `Nullable<int>`.

Nullable types in C# are just a "syntactic sugar". At compile time, the compiler replaces all the `int?` and `double?` and `bool?` with `Nullable<int>`, `Nullable<double>` and `Nullable<bool>`.

Note that `Nullable<T>` is actually a *struct*! So technically it can never be null! The reason why you can assign null to a nullable type is yet another syntactic sugar. When you assign null to a nullable type, it sets its `HasValue` property to false. When you assign a non-null value to it, it sets `HasValue` to true again and sets the underlying value to the value that you're setting.

That's a brief description of how nullable types works. Now back to your question:

> But we when we access HasValue property of a Nullable object, it will gives a result

I guess you mean

> But when we access `HashValue` property of a, say `int?`, it will never throw an exception, even if the variable is `null`! Why?

As I said before, `Nullable<T>` is a struct, so it can never be null. That's why you can access the `HasValue` property and never throw an exception.

"But why accessing the `Value` property of a nullable object sometimes throws an exception?" you might ask.

That's because of the implementation of the `Nullable<T>` struct. As you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e):

```
public T Value {
    get {
        if (!hasValue) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_NoValue);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

It checks that if `hasValue` is true. If it is false, throw an exception.

So that's why.